# HttpClient Error Code 500 but can't replicate issue with BURP Suite?

Tags: java, post, apache-commons-httpclient

I wrote a program that sends POST JSON objects to a website. It worked fine, and one day it started throwing 500 errors. So I ran it under a proxy, no dice. I can't replicate this issue with a browser, or BURP suite. It has the exact headers, exact objects, exact agent-type, the whole nine yards. Word for word how BURP sends it to me. What could be a possibility? I tried several proxies. I tried copying every single cookie. There's a CSRFToken but it's valid, it's the same one I used when sending a POST request in BURP Suite.

Again, went to sleep my code was working fine (200 status codes) and now I'm getting 500 status codes. I can't post the code at the moment because I'm not home. I've been searching google & stackoverflow for the past few days now.

Comment: I don't know what BURP or CSRFToken is, but when the server sends back a 500, it means it effectively crashed processing your request or it's a bad state.   It's entirely possible that your code is fine, but the server is broken. If you don't have access to the server, as the server admin to investigate.  Were you getting exactly a "500" back and was there any content to go with it?  Or was it 502 or 504 (which implies a proxy server on your network is choking on the request).

Comment: A Wireshark or Fiddler capture of your network session will likely reveal the issue.

Comment: I'll give wireshark or fiddler a shot, I just tested the same code on a different computer and it works fine. Strange, I doubt it's anything firewall related.